# from the spacemacs shell, how do I edit a file in a new buffer in the main window?

Tags: spacemacs, shell-mode

I open a new shell using <kbd>space</kbd>-<kbd>'</kbd>. From that shell window I can type `ls` to see files. Let's say I want to edit `~/.zshrc`. From the shell prompt, what do I type to edit that file in a new buffer in the main window?

Note - I do not want to browse to the file location again using <kbd>space</kbd>-<kbd>f</kbd>-<kbd>f</kbd>, as I might be several dirs deep. And typing `emacs <filename>` opens a new instance of Emacs. `vim <filename>` works close to what I want.

I'm using Macos with the d12frosted homebrew install of Emacs.

Answer (score 1):

Add `export ALTERNATE_EDITOR="" #Causes Emacs to start a daemon if one is not found.` to somewhere your system shell sources (e.g., ~/.profile_bash). Then you can use `emacsclient "PATH"` to open a file in your current emacs session.